# How to filter and sort objects by key in Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object, filter

I'm trying to sort objects by key in my React App. I have an object (data) and string values(someString), I need to sort and filter my obj by its keys according to this someString's values and in the same order. So far I was able to filter and sort objects by key values from someString, the problem is that I don't know how to display values of the object after I sorted it by key, right now only keys are getting displayed.

My code is:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const data = {
    info: {
      name: "Jane Smith",
      info: "26 years old"
    },

    newInfo: {
      name: "John Smith",
      info: "35 years old"
    },

    updatedInfo: {
      name: "James Smith",
      info: "45 years old"
    },
    latestUpdate: {
      name: "J D",
      info: "23 years old"
    }
  };

  let someString = "newInfo,latestUpdate,updatedInfo";

  let newData = Object.keys(data)?.filter((i) => someString.includes(i));

  const sorted = newData.sort((a, b) => {
    const aIndex = someString.indexOf(a);
    const bIndex = someString.indexOf(b);
    return aIndex - bIndex;
  });

  console.log(sorted, "sorted");

  
  return <div className="App">{sorted}</div>;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dirac-p9tu7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The code is displaying "sorted" as

```
0: "newInfo"
1: "latestUpdate"
2: "updatedInfo"
```

but I need for sorted to have also object's values like this:

```
 newInfo: {
      name: "John Smith",
      info: "35 years old"
    },
latestUpdate: {
      name: "J D",
      info: "23 years old"
    },
  updatedInfo: {
      name: "James Smith",
      info: "45 years old"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting, turn them into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const data = {
  info: {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    info: "26 years old"
  },

  newInfo: {
    name: "John Smith",
    info: "35 years old"
  },

  updatedInfo: {
    name: "James Smith",
    info: "45 years old"
  },
  latestUpdate: {
    name: "J D",
    info: "23 years old"
  }
};

const someString = "newInfo,latestUpdate,updatedInfo";


const keys = Object.keys(data).filter(key => someString.includes(key));
const sortedObj = Object.fromEntries(
  keys
    .sort((a, b) => someString.indexOf(a) - someString.indexOf(b))
    .map(key => [key, data[key]])
);
console.log(sortedObj);
```